# Rotation around the diameter in Riemann sphere

Tags: complex-analysis, stereographic-projections, riemann-sphere

Consider Riemann sphere

[image]

And consider the following projection :

The plane $\zeta =0 $ here is the complex plane, and consider the following map:

Each point (except the north pole) of the sphere, being mapped to $ \left(\xi,\eta,\zeta\right)\to\left(\frac{\xi}{1-\zeta},\frac{\eta}{1-\zeta},0\right) $

And conversly, the point on the sphere that is being mapped to $(x,y,0) $ given by

$$ \left(\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}+1},\frac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}+1},\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}\right)\to\left(x,y,0\right) $$

Now, I want to show that the function $ \frac{1}{z},z\in\mathbb{C} $ is represented on the sphere by a $ 180^{\circ} $ rotation about the diameter with endpoints $ \left(-\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{2}\right),\left(\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{2}\right) $

What I have done :

I proved that given a point $ z $ which is the image of a point $ \left(\xi,\eta,\zeta\right) $ on the sphere, the point which is mapped to $\frac{1}{z} $ on the sphere, is the point $ \left(\xi,-\eta,1-\zeta\right) $.

So all thre's left to do is to prove that given a point on the sphere $ \left(\xi,\eta,\zeta\right) $, its rotation about the diameter that I mentioned by $180^{\circ} $ is indeed $ \left(\xi,-\eta,1-\zeta\right) $.

I dont know how to express the rotation since its in 3 dimensions and Im not familier with this. So I'd really apreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the transformation of the coordinate system
$$ 
\begin{align}
\xi &= u \\
\eta &= v \\
\zeta &= w + 1/2
\end{align}
$$
the mapping
$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
 \xi \\ \eta \\ \zeta
 \end{pmatrix}
\mapsto
 \begin{pmatrix}
 \xi \\ -\eta \\ 1-\zeta
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
becomes
$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
 u \\ v \\ w
 \end{pmatrix}
\mapsto
 \begin{pmatrix}
 u \\ -v \\ -w
 \end{pmatrix}
=  \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0& -1  
 \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
 u \\ v \\ w
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and that is a rotation about the $u$-axis by $180$ degrees, compare [basic 3d rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions).

So the original mapping is a rotation by $180$ degrees, and the rotation axis is the $\xi$-axis translated by $1/2$ in the direction of the positive $\zeta$-axis (which is what you wanted to show).