# How to compute the differential of $f:S^2 \rightarrow S^2, z \mapsto 1/z$ at the north and south pole?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

> Consider the identification $\mathbb{C} \cup \{ \infty \} \simeq S^2$. Show that $f:S^2 \rightarrow S^2, z \mapsto 1/z$ is a $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ function and compute its differentials in the north and south poles.

I understand (see for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4223123/rotation-around-the-diameter-in-riemann-sphere)) that we may view this map as a rotation of $S^2$ by 180 degrees about the diameter with endpoints $(-1/2,0,1/2)$ and $(1/2,0,1/2)$ and that it may be represented by the matrix

$$f(x,y,z) = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ -y \\-z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 & 0 \\ 0 &-1 & 0 \\ 0 &0 &-1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}$$

and we know that linear maps are smooth.

Now to the differential. If I am not mistaken the differential can be computed via the Jacobi matrix.

However, then we would have

$$Df=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 & 0 \\ 0 &-1 & 0 \\ 0 &0 &-1 \end{pmatrix}$$

, but I do not think that this is correct. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: $f$ is a map from a two dimensional manifold to itself. Its differential at a point has to be a linear map from a two dimensional vector space to another one. Therefore, your computations can't be right.
Note that $f$ being a diffeomorphism will force the differential at any point to be a linear isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, I still do not understand what I am doing wrong here. I know that the matrix of a differential $f:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a Jacobi matrix, so I computed the Jacobi matrix of $f$, but I do not think that this works in that way.

Comment: Your $f$ is not a map $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, but a map $S^2\rightarrow S^2$. To compute this differential, you can either work in charts, which leads to computing $2\times 2$ Jacobians, or you can interpret this as a restriction of a function $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$, compute its Jacobian and then restrict this map to the respective tangent spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the linked question the sphere $S^2$ has center $(0,0,1/2)$ and radius $1/2$. A more standard interpretation is to regard it as
$$S^2 = \{ p \in \mathbb R^3 \mid \lVert p \rVert = 1 \}$$
which is centered at the origin and radius $1$.

Stereographic projection from the north pole is given by the same formula as in [Rotation around the diameter in Riemann sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4223123). Using the same approach as in its answer one can see that the function $1/ z : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ corresponds to a rotation of $S^2$ around the $x$-axis by an angle of $180^o$.

This rotation is a linear automorphism $R : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ which is described by the matrix $$M_R =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0& -1  
 \end{pmatrix} .$$
Its differential has indeed Jacobian matrix $JR\mid_p = M_R$ at all $p \in \mathbb R^3$.

$R$ restricts to a smooth map $r : S^2 \to S^2$ which rotates $S^2$ around the $x$-axis by $180^o$. Its differential at the north pole $n$ is $Dr \mid_n : T_nS^2 \to T_sS^2$ from the tangent space $T_nS^2$ at $n$ to the tangent space $T_sS^2$ at the south pole $s$ .

Both tangent spaces are $\bar{\mathbb R}^2 = \mathbb R^2 \times \{0\}$ = $x$-$y$-plane in $\mathbb R^3$. We have the following commutative diagram:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\bar{\mathbb R}^2 = T_nS^2 @>{Dr \mid_n}>> T_sS^2 = \bar{\mathbb R}^2\\
@V{}VV @VV{}V \\
\mathbb R^3 = T_n\mathbb R^3 @>>{DR \mid_n}> T_s\mathbb R^3 = \mathbb R^3\end{CD}
Here the vertical arrows are inclusion maps.

This shows that
$$Dr \mid_n(x,y,0) = (x,-y,0) .$$

The same is true for $Dr \mid_s : T_sS^2 \to T_nS^2$.

Both maps are reflections in the $x$-axis of $\bar{\mathbb R}^2$.